# tensorflow model fit: ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, imagedatagenerator

I'm building dual channel CNN model for image classification. First training data is `'gyro_training_gen'` and next one is `'acc_training_gen'`. Both of them created with using keras `'ImageDataGenerator'`.

Below is my code building and training model and data generation process.

```
training_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255,
    validation_split = 0.2
)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

gyro_training_gen= training_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    GYRO_TRAINING_DIR,
    #target_size = (400,400,1),
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
    color_mode = 'grayscale',
    class_mode = 'categorical',
    subset = 'training'
)

acc_training_gen = training_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    ACC_TRAINING_DIR,
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
    #target_size = (400,400,1),
    color_mode = 'grayscale',
    class_mode = 'categorical',
    subset = 'training'
)

def define_model(input_shape):
    
    #channel - gyro
    inputs1 = Input(shape=(input_shape))
    conv1 = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(8,8), activation='relu')(inputs1)
    drop1 = Dropout(0.5)(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(drop1)
    flat1 = Flatten()(pool1)
    
     #channel 2 - acc
    inputs2 = Input(shape=(input_shape))
    conv2 = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(8,8), activation='relu')(inputs2)
    drop2 = Dropout(0.5)(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(drop2)
    flat2 = Flatten()(pool2)
    
    #merge
    merged = Concatenate()([flat1, flat2])
        
     #interpretation
    dense1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(merged)
    outputs = Dense(8, activation='softmax')(dense1)
    model = Model(inputs=[inputs1, inputs2], outputs=outputs)
    
    #compile
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
                  optimizer=Adam(learning_rate= LEARNING_RATE), 
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
     #summarize
    print(model.summary())
    plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, to_file = 'DCNN.png')
    
    return model

checkpoint_cb = ModelCheckpoint('DDcares_DCNN.h5', save_best_only = True)

model.fit(
    [gyro_training_gen, acc_training_gen],
    #steps_per_epoch = len(gyro_training_gen),
    epochs = 20,
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
    callbacks = [checkpoint_cb]
)
```

And it gives me error: `ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator'>"}), <class 'NoneType'>`

Can anyone help me to solve this error ?
Thank you :)

Modify generator function and input shape but couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue tf.data.Dataset for Keras multi-input model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64770484/issue-tf-data-dataset-for-keras-multi-input-model)